# Rails 4: Limit field selection through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-record-query

I know you can limit the returned fields in a Rails query by doing:

```
c = Client.select(:id, :user_id, :location_id).where(name: "John Doe")
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Client id: 349, user_id: 348, location_id: 2>]>
```

but if you can only access the model through an association, how can you accomplish the same?  (in this example `Client` `belongs_to :user`)

```
User.find_by(email: "johndoe@email.com").client # I only want the 3 fields above
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it for example using scope, instead of association method:

```
Client.select(:id, :user_id, :location_id)
      .find_by(user_id: User.find_by(email: 'johndoe@email.com').id)
```

or even better, joining `user` and querying directly over users.email column:

```
Client.select(:id, :user_id, :location_id)
      .joins(:user).find_by(users: { email: 'johndoe@email.com' })
```